# Communicating between child and parent components with ngAfterViewInit

Tags: javascript, angular

So I try to communicate between components with `ngAfterViewInit`.

And I want to use the property

```
participant: ParticipantInfoDTO;
```

also using in other component. So I try it like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.scss'],
  template: 'Example: {{participant}}<app-echeq-selector></app-echeq-selector>'
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(EcheqSelectorComponent) echeqReference: ParticipantInfoDTO;

  participant: ParticipantInfoDTO;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.participant = route.snapshot.data['participant'];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.participant = this.echeqReference;
  }
}
```

And in child component(`EcheqSelectorComponent`) I want it using like this:

```
<p> selected id:{{participant}} </p>
```

But I get an error on this line:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.scss'],
  template: 'Example: {{participant}}<app-echeq-selector></app-echeq-selector>'
})
```

saying:

> Component '`DetailComponent`' must not have both template and
>   `templateUrlng(0)`

Thank you

Comment: Just use one html file. You are trying to use two html files for one component.

Comment: What I have to change then?

Comment: It's up to you, keep what you want and remove the other. If you want both you can add the elements to the html file.

Comment: Yes, oke, but how can I use that propertie then in other component?

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove template property in your component decorator.
In detail.component.html, add all the elements you want so that your html file looks like this:

```
Example: {{participant}}<app-echeq-selector></app-echeq-selector>
```

If you want to pass a property to app-echeq-selector component then you can use property binding like this:

```
<app-echeq-selector [participant]="participant"></app-echeq-selector>
```

In echeq component.ts:

```
export class echeq... {
 @Input() participant;
 // you can use this participant property as you want now.
}
```